# Submit a form from a grand-parent component with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i have built a Template-Driven form in one of my components. This form-component is a grandchild of a component which has a submit button. I need to submit the form from the grand-parent and to keep the same user input validation (with the ngForm validity). I have seen some documentation using the @ViewChild decorator but I could not apply it to a grand-child.

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

I am going to show the main parts of the code for simplicity:

The form is placed in right-panel.component.html / right-panel.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'vp-rightpanel',
templateUrl: 'right-panel.component.html',
styleUrls: ['right-panel.component.css'],
moduleId: module.id
})
export class RightPanelComponent implements OnChanges , OnInit{...
```

The Parent component is candidate-verification.component.html/ candidate-verification.component.ts

```
<div class="col-md-6 right-panel-container">
    <vp-rightpanel *ngIf="showRightpanel" [rating]="starRating" (openAddEditWorkHistoryClicked)="onOpenAddEditWorkHistoryClicked($event)"></vp-rightpanel>       
</div>
```

The grand-parent component is app.component.ts / app.component.html which inject the container (candidate-verification.component.ts) using routes, but this is the ONE which has the submit button:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">            
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                               
            <li><button (click)="saveAndFinish()"type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Save and Finish</button></li>                 
        </ul>
 </div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The module which imports and manage the routes looks like this:

```
const childRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'candidate-verification', component: CandidateVerificationComponent     
},
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'candidate-verification', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
...
declarations: [  
    CandidateVerificationComponent,
    RightPanelComponent
]
 ...
```

This how the app looks like:

[image]

I hope this clear to get some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see angularjs here

Comment: It is Angular 2 using typescript